# Como incluir um arquivo criado style.css no meu projeto blank IONIC 3

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2, ionic-popup

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

me ajudem a colocar o css no ionic, so funciona se eu colocar estilo inline

Comment: @PéttrinMiranda como assim o arquivo **index.html** não é o arquivo certo?! O index.html é o arquivo principal da aplicação, sendo feito por ele a renderização das demais tela no projeto, ou seja, tudo que for declarado dentro dele tem o escopo como sendo  **global** inclusive **`Css`**.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não tenho tanta certeza se esse método é efetivo, Ionic funciona com um sistema de paginas que possui seu próprio css(no caso do ionic é scss). Caso não saiba criar uma pagina o comando é o seguinte `ionic g page nome_da_pagina`.
No seu caso resta duas perguntas, esse seu css você deseja usar em uma única pagina ou usar em todas?

Caso a resposta seja uma única pagina, você pode colocar seu css dentro da pagina que deseja(no caso em questão login.scss)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou caso queira que seu css seja reconhecido em todo o projeto adicione ele em um componente chamado app.scss

[image: css global]
[image: app.scss]

> Para saber mais sobre estilização no [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/)